# Convert user input into array to be generated into many different variations

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, user-input

When a user inputs a sentence into the title box they are supposed to be able to generate 72 different variations of that title with words being replaced and words changing positions. The problem that is occurring is that it will not take the user input and do anything with it. It works if you pre-define the text within the array.

Below is the html used.

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Title Generation Module</title>
<script src="title.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="find.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="replace.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="search.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="generate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- <script src="check.js" type="text/javascript"></script>--> <!-- Leaving for future usage not needed at this point -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="title.css">
</head>
<body>

<h1>Title Generation Module</h1>   
    <div id="cWords">
    <h3>Words That Might Return an Invalid Title</h3>
    <ul>
    <li>For</li>
    <li>You</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>With</li>
    <li>Adaptor</li>
    <li>Wireless</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
<!-- This allows the user to input a title -->
    <h3>Input Title into Text Field</h3>
    <input type="text" id="title" style="height:20px; width: 500px;">
        <p>Click the Submit button. To see if the title is a good working title click on the check title button below.</p>
        <button onclick="getTitle()">Submit</button>
        <p id="displayTitle" class="title"></p>
<!-- This allows the user to hightllight a keyword in the Title -->
    <p>Find Keywords in your sentence</p>
        <input id="kText">
            <button onclick="getSearch()">Search</button>
<!-- This allows the user to change the keyword within a title to a new word -->
    <p>Changes You Want to Make to Keywords</p>
        <input type="text" id="change">
        <button onclick="newTitle()">Change Keyword</button>
<!-- Button Reloads the page -->        
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Reload page</button>
<!-- Reloads the page -->
    <script>
        function myFunction()
    {
        location.reload();
    }
    </script>
<!-- Change the Order of the Title -->
    <button onclick="generate_title()">Generate Title</button>
    <button onclick="displayTitle()">Display Title</button>
    <script>
        function displayTitle()
        {
            var dpTitle = document.getElementById("displayTitle").innerHTML;
            alert(dpTitle);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is the javascript that will handle the function of replacing and displaying the user input.

```
var keyword = document.getElementById("displayTitle").innerHTML;
   var kText = document.getElementById("kText").value;
   var changeWord = document.getElementById("change").value;
   var newKeyword = new Array(keyword);

   newKeyword = keyword.split(kText).join(changeWord); 

var input_keywords = 
 [
    [check],
    //[checkY,checkY],
    ["Cordless-","Wireless"],
    ["Rechargeable+"],
    ["you"]
    ].filter(function(item){
    return item.length <= 80;
    });


        /*[
           ["Men", "Women", "Unisex"],
           ["1", "2", "3", "fourrrrrrrrrr"],
           ["Candy Color"],
           ["Spring"],
           ["Ski+"],
           ["Crochet"],
           ["Hip-hop"],
           ["Hat Beanie-"],
           ["One Size+"]].filter(function(item)
           {
               return item.length <= 80;
           });
        */

        /*
        var input_keywords = [
                ["Women Men", "Men Women", "Unisex Women Men", "Unisex Men Women", "Unisex", "Womens Mens", "Mens Womens", "Unisex Womens Mens", "Unisex Mens Womens"],
                ["Fashion", "Trendy", "Stylish", "Korea Style"],
                ["Candy Color"],
                ["Spring", "Summer", "Winter"],
                ["Ski"],
                ["Crochet", "Knit", "Knitted"],
                ["Elastic", "Strechable"],
                ["Hip-hop", "Dance"],
                ["Hat", "Cap", "Beanie", "Hat Cap", "Hat Beanie", "Hat Cap Beanie"],
                ["One Size"]
            ].filter(function(item){
                return item.length <= 80;
            });
        */
    var limit_count = 1;
    var max_char_per_title = 80;
    var sub_library = ["for=4", "you=u", "at=@", "two=2", "with=w", "adapter=adpt", "Monokini=Mono 9"].map( function (item)
        { return item.split("=");});
function calc_length(title)
    {
        return (title
        .join(" ") + " ")
        .replace("- ", " ")
        .replace("+ ", " ")
        .replace("* ", " ")
        .replace("  ", " ")
        .replace("\" ", " ")
        .replace(" \"", " ")
        .length - 1;

    }
function get_all_titles(keywords)
    {
        var result_titles = [];

        for(var i = 0; i < keywords.length; i ++)
        {
            var word_count = keywords[i].length;
            var words = keywords[i];
            var previous_count = result_titles.length;
            if (previous_count == 0)
                {
                    previous_count = word_count;
                    for (var sub_ii = 0 ; sub_ii < word_count; sub_ii++)
                    {
                        result_titles[sub_ii] = [];
                        result_titles[sub_ii][i] = words[sub_ii];
                    }
                }
            else
                {
                    for (var sub_i = 0; sub_i < word_count; sub_i++)
                    {
                        for (var sub_ii = 0 ; sub_ii < previous_count; sub_ii++)
                            {
                                if (result_titles[previous_count * sub_i + sub_ii] == undefined)
                                    {
                                        result_titles[previous_count * sub_i + sub_ii] = result_titles[sub_ii                                          ].slice();
                                    } 
                                result_titles[previous_count * sub_i + sub_ii][i] = words[sub_i];
                            }
                    }
                }
        }
        return result_titles;
    }

function substitute(title)
    {
        for (var subs_idx = 0 ; subs_idx < sub_library.length; subs_idx++)
        {
            var index = title.indexOf(sub_library[subs_idx][0]);
            if (index >= 0)
            {
                title[index] = sub_library[subs_idx][1];
            }  
        }
        return title;
    }

function shorten_title_length(titles)
    {
        var result = [];
        var count = 0;
        for (var i = 0 ; i < titles.length; i++)
            {
                if (calc_length(titles[i]) > max_char_per_title)
                {
                    //substitute with the word in library
                    titles[i] = substitute(titles[i]);
                    // still too long, remove possible words.
                    if (calc_length(titles[i]) > max_char_per_title)
                    {
                        var words = titles[i];
                        for (var word_idx = 0 ; word_idx < words.length; word_idx++)
                        { 
                            if (words[word_idx].indexOf("/") == (words[word_idx].length - 1))
                            {
                                titles[i] = titles[i].splice(word_idx, 1);
                            }

                        }
                        titles[i] = words
                    }
                }
                if (calc_length(titles[i]) <= max_char_per_title)
                    {
                        result[count] = titles[i];
                        count++;
                    }
                else
                {
                    console.log(titles[i].join(" \ "));
                }
            }
            return result;
    }

function change_forward_position(title)
    {
        var words = title;
        for (var word_idx = 0 ; word_idx < words.length; word_idx++)
        {
            if (words[word_idx][words[word_idx].length - 1] == "-")
            {
                if (word_idx != words.length - 1)
                {
                    var tmp = words[word_idx];
                    words[word_idx] = words[word_idx + 1];
                    words[word_idx + 1] = tmp;
                    word_idx ++;
                }
            }
        }
        title = words;
        return title;
    }

function change_backward_position(title)
    {
        var words = title;
        for (var word_idx = 0 ; word_idx < words.length; word_idx++)
        {
            if (words[word_idx][words[word_idx].length - 1] == "+")
            {
                if (word_idx != 0)
                {
                    var tmp = words[word_idx];
                    words[word_idx] = words[word_idx - 1];
                    words[word_idx - 1] = tmp;
                }
            }
        }
        title = words;
        return title;
    }

function finalize(titles)
    {
        for (var title_idx = 0 ; title_idx < titles.length; title_idx++)
        {
            for (var word_idx = 0 ; word_idx < titles[title_idx].length; word_idx++)
            {
                if (titles[title_idx][word_idx][titles[title_idx][word_idx].length - 1] == '+')
                    titles[title_idx][word_idx] = titles[title_idx][word_idx].substring(0, titles[title_idx][word_idx].length -                     1);
                if (titles[title_idx][word_idx][titles[title_idx][word_idx].length - 1] == '-')
                    titles[title_idx][word_idx] = titles[title_idx][word_idx].substring(0, titles[title_idx][word_idx].length -                     1);
                if (titles[title_idx][word_idx][titles[title_idx][word_idx].length - 1] == '/')
                    titles[title_idx][word_idx] = titles[title_idx][word_idx].substring(0, titles[title_idx][word_idx].length -                     1);
                if (titles[title_idx][word_idx][titles[title_idx][word_idx].length - 1] == '"')
                    titles[title_idx][word_idx] = titles[title_idx][word_idx].substring(0, titles[title_idx][word_idx].length -                     1);
                if (titles[title_idx][word_idx][titles[title_idx][word_idx].length - 1] == '*')
                    titles[title_idx][word_idx] = titles[title_idx][word_idx].substring(0, titles[title_idx][word_idx].length -                     1);
            }
        }
        return titles;
    }

function generate_title()
    {

        var all_titles = get_all_titles(newKeyword);
        //Check keyword files provided by the user, that optional sub words are at least 24
        if (all_titles.length < limit_count)
        {
            alert("not enough different titles");
        }
        //check total char per title
        all_titles = shorten_title_length(all_titles);
        // substitute half randomly.
        for (var i = 0 ; i < all_titles.length; i++)
        { 
            if (Math.random() > 0.5)
            {
                all_titles[i] = substitute(all_titles[i]);
            }
        }
        //changing position backward.
        for (var i = 0 ; i < all_titles.length; i++)
        { 
            if (Math.random() > 0.5)
            {
                all_titles[i] = change_backward_position(all_titles[i]);
            }
        }
        //changing position forward.
        for (var i = 0 ; i < all_titles.length; i++)
        { 
            if (Math.random() > 0.5)
            {
                all_titles[i] = change_forward_position(all_titles[i]);
            }
        }
        all_titles = finalize(all_titles);
        // evaluate.....
        for (var i = 0 ; i < all_titles.length; i++)
        {
            console.log(i);
            console.log(all_titles[i].join(" \ "));
            console.log(all_titles[i].length);
            alert(all_titles);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you set this up in https://jsfiddle.net/ so we can see the problem you are having in action?

Comment: It isn't even clear what you are asking...if we don't know what the problem is, and you can't show the minimum required code to duplicate the issue, then it's going to be hard for us to help. Consider modifying your question to actually contain a question...

Comment: I put the files into dropbox for anyone to download and see since JSFiddle won't allow me to accurately put it on their site

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/gp6foo297fs4d8a/AAADyEsroJqsXuMurwnEGbp1a?dl=0
@LanguidSquid

Comment: when a user inputs a sentence into the title box they are supposed to be able to generate 72 different variations of that title with words being replaced and words changing positions. The problem that is occurring is that it will not take the user input and do anything with it. It works if you pre-define the text within the array. @LanguidSquid

Comment: @LanguidSquid heres a https://jsfiddle.net/g0tmc6u8/